# How to use a variable in a LINQ to ENTITIES select statement?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

I want to select some rows from a table called "Customer", but it seems wrong when I define the tableName with "db.Customer" . Is there any way I can do it?

```
            string tableName = "db.Customer";
            var result = from p in tableName 
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = p.ID,
                         Des = p.Description,
                         type = p.Type,
                         date = p.DateCreated

                     };
        gridview.DataSource = result;
        gridview.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CreateQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670.aspx) method (receives an Entity SQL command)

```
var result = ctx.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(@"select p.ID, 
                                                        p.Description,
                                                        p.Type, 
                                                        p.DateCreated 
                                                 from Customer as p");
```

or [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx) (to execute T-SQL)

```
   var result = ctx.ExecuteStoreQuery<CustomerInfo>(@"select p.ID, 
                                                            p.Description,
                                                            p.Type, 
                                                            p.DateCreated 
                                                     from dbo.Customer as p");


public class CustomerInfo
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public int Type {get; set;}
   public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}
}
```